# pyinstaller module-error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Когда хочу собрать приложение в один .exe файл этой командой в cmd:

```
pyinstaller -F -w -i C:\Users\clipper.exe C:\Users\clipper.py
```

Выдает:

```
File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 190, in CopyIcons
except win32api.error as W32E:
AttributeError: module 'win32ctypes.pywin32.win32api' has no attribute 'error'
```

Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейдите в директорию с программой. Не нужно писать название выходного файла с .exe и его путь, т.к. вполне просто его переименовать, да и сам он в любом случае выйдет .exe формата.

```
>>> pyinstaller -F -w -i (название вашей иконки ***.ico) clipper.py
```

Comment: Компиляция прошла, но все равно дальше по коду вылетел еще один неизвестный error:

`self._fields_ = list(struct.unpack(self._format_, data)) struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 6 bytes`

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет этот ответ. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110581/9624362